# Reroute user if conditions are met

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

I'm trying to add a condition in my Router which redirects a user if it is the users first time on the app. When a user logs in an object is returned with the property `firstTime` which can be either true or false.

I am attempting to use a ternary operator as follows:

```
const ClientRoutes = ({ openHelp }) => {
  const firstTime = true;

  return (
    <div>
      <Location>
        {({ location }) => (
          <Router location={location} primary={false}>

            {firstTime ? navigate("/welcome") : null}

            <ClientDocFolders path="/" />
            <WelcomePageContainer path="/welcome" />
            <ErrorNotFound default />
          </Router>
        )}
      </Location>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withClient(ClientRoutes);
```

This gives me an error saying:
`Error: Objects are not valid as a React child`
I have also tried replacing the `navigate("/welcome")` with a function call like this: `{firstTime ? openHelp() : null}` or `{firstTime ? ()=> openHelp() : null}`.  The first of these works in redirecting me, however the function gets called repeatedly without end.  The second function just doesn't work (my open help function never runs).

I am using reach-router but I think this issue has to do with the JS.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Redirect` component for redirect and `localStorage` could be used to save the user status.

Or you could use `useEffect` hook to navigate.

> Note: `localStorage` will keep the data on client side and user can delete this data anytime, so I will recommend to save the data in some backend database.

```
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const isNewUser = localStorage.getItem("isNewUser")
      ? localStorage.getItem("isNewUser")
      : localStorage.setItem("isNewUser", false);
    if (!isNewUser) {
      navigate("/welcome");
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Tutorial!</h1>
      <nav>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <Link to="dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
      </nav>
      <br />
      <Router primary="{false}">
          <ClientDocFolders path="/" />
          <WelcomePageContainer path="/welcome" />
          <ErrorNotFound default />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Without React Hook**

[image: Edit Reroute user if conditions are met]

**With React Hook and navigate**

[image: Edit Reroute user if conditions are met / With React Hook]

Comment: I get the following error: `Error: [object Object]`   I also only want the redirect to happen one time. So the second time the user tries to go to "/" they shouldn't be redirected.

Comment: Same error as before :/ . It feels like I can't run functions from inside the return method here.  I do have a solution which calls `useEffect` before the return statement, but I would like to avoid this if possible.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure.  I inherited that part of the code, but I think it is used to pass animation effects?  Here is the doc https://reach.tech/router/api/Location

Comment: I'm getting the same error still.  The issue is with the `<Redirect />` though not with the `firstTime` variable.  If I try something like `{firstTime ? console.log('true'): console.log('false') }` . I can see that 'true' is logged.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206804/discussion-between-sohail-and-tdammon).